# Как сделать переход на другое activity в android?

Tags: android

У меня есть два activity. В первом по нажатию на кнопку я стартую второе activity. Как мне перейти со второго activity на первое?

P.s.
Для этого я вызывал во втором startActivity, но он создает новое activity, а мне надо перейти к старому, уже существующему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во второй активити вызовите метод завершения оной так:

`finish()`

Comment: Можно передать данные, полученные в ходе работы второго activity? Передать их в первое

Comment: @Харрис, да, можно. Для этого надо 1. запускать 2 активити через `startActivityForResult()` 2. Перед `finish()` вызвать `setResult(bundleWithData)` 3. В первой активити принять `bundleWithData` в методе `onActivityResult()`